# Arrange 20 counters and remove 6 form them and not a single square can be indicated?

Tags: combinatorics

Arrange 20 counters in the
form of a PLUS(+), as you can see
in the image.

Now, how many
different ways are there in which four
counters will form a perfect
square if considered alone? Thus the
four counters composing each arm of
the PLUS(+), and also there is four in the
center of it, form squares.

Squares are also
formed by the four counters marked
A, the four marked B, and so on.

How will you remove 6 counters from it
so that not a single square can be so
indicated from those that are still there?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are

> 21 squares

Counting

> 9 of this variety (2 on each leg plus the central one)
>  [image]
>  4 of this variety  (can move this shape right, down or right+down).
>  [image]
>  These 4
>  [image]
>  And these four
>  [image]

I would remove these counters

> [image]

Comment: Checked you might ignored the square of length $2\sqrt{2}$ :D